# Navigation Bar en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy realizando una aplicación con Android Studio en la que necesito que la barra de navegación (la barra que permite volver atrás, volver al home, etc...) **NO APAREZCA NUNCA**. He conseguido ocultarla gracias a estas líneas de código:

```
   private void hideSystemUI() {
    View decorView = Activity.this.getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

pero no me sirve porque aunque la oculta, al deslizar el dedo en la zona donde tendría que estar la barra vuelve a aparecer. ¿Alguna forma de solucionar esto? Por aquí solo he encontrado formas para ocultarla pero no de eliminarla definitivamente. Gracias.

Comment: Podrías color alguna imagen para ver el tipo de navegación que estas utilizando, y una explicación de porque la nueva vista no debe tener navegación para entender el contexto.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer una barra de herramientas, primero hay que ocultar la que viene por de fecto para crear un archivo nuevo y configurar la tuya propia desde el nuevo archivo, para ocultarla tienes que abrir el archivo "styles.xml" ubicado en **res/values** y cambiar esta linea:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Donde pone DarkActionBar, tienes que sustituirlo por NoActionBar:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Ahora que ya has ocultado la barra que viene por defecto, tienes que crear la tuya propia, de esta manera:

1-Ve a la carpeta layout y crea un nuevo "Layout resource file"

2-Debe de quedar algo asi:https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWakb.png

Este es el codigo que suelo usar yo para el nuevo recurso:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

En la clase main activity, o en la que quieras usar la barra de tareas, pon este codigo en el metodo onCreate:

```
setSupportActionBar((androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
```

Y en esa misma clase, en el archivo xml, incluye la nueva barra de tareas:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

Aqui dejo un enlace para unos tutoriales de como cambiar el aspecto, color, opciones....

https://youtu.be/DMkzIOLppf4
https://youtu.be/oh4YOj9VkVE

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo y responder pero lo que yo quiero hacer no es crear otra barra nueva, es simplemente, que no se muestre nunca.